# Fetch child and parent - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In `laravel` I have the below 2 models;
This is the `parent`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RestaurantClass extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the restaurants for the restaurant class.
     */
    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Restaurant');
    }
}
```

And this is the `child`;

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Restaurant extends Model
{    
    /**
     * Get the restaurant class that owns the restaurant.
     */
    public function restaurantClass()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\RestaurantClass');
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the child and it's parent and vice versa (retrieve the parent and all its children)

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To query relationships in Laravel, use the `with($relation)` method
>   on the model class you want.

Applying this to your example would be like :

Retreive the parent with its children :

```
$restaurantClasses = RestaurantClass::with('restaurants')->get();

// to access "children" 
foreach($restaurantClasses as $restaurantClass) {
  $restaurantClass->restaurants;
}
```

Retreive the children with their parent :

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::with('restaurantClass')->get();

// to access "parent" models
foreach($restaurants as $restaurant) {
  $restaurant->restaurantClass;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()` when I use `all()` but it works when I use `get()`

Comment: So can I do something like this;

`grandparent-parent-child-grandchild`?

Comment: @moh.ABK I don't think I understand what are you trying to achieve, but with this set up you can only access the instance in one level, `parent => children` or `child => parents`

Comment: Alright. Yeah my question is can I access multiple levels also? With a different setup? `parent => children => grandchildren`?

Comment: I don't think it could be possible with Eloquent, as far as I know the only solution is to create 3 classes `parent`, `children` & `grandchildren` and define the relationships as demonstrated in my response.

This lack of expression in class hierarchy is due to Active Record pattern that Eloquent implements instead of Data Mapper pattern (e.g Doctrine)

Comment: Yeah I meant have 3 classes and then query. Thanks for you help, I found it in the docs... `$books = App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have your **RestaurantClass** model like the following:

```
class RestaurantClass extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'ID',
        'NAME',    
    ];

    /**
     * Get the restaurants for the restaurant class.
     */
    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Restaurant');
    }
}
```

and your **Restaurant** model looks like this:

```
class Restaurant extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable = [
        'ID',
        'NAME',
        'RestaurantClassId',    
    ];
    /**
     * Get the restaurant class that owns the restaurant.
     */
    public function restaurantClass()
    {
        // Associating RestaurantClass and Restauran through their ids..
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\RestaurantClass', 'RestaurantClassId', 'ID');
    }
}
```

Now inside your controller you can use this relationship in several ways, for instance:

```
RestaurantController::with('restaurantClass')->findOrFail($id); // This will bring up all the restaurant classes and you can later use it in your view like $data->restaurantClass->NAME ..
```

Or you can use it inside your create/edit function in your controller like the following example and then further use it in your view:

```
$dataSet = array(
            'restaurantClass' => RestaurantClass::lists('NAME', 'ID')
            );
```

I hope this solution helped you and provided you with some insight how relationship works, however you can turn relationship the other way around to make it work in opposite direction as in, RestaurantClass would have this belongsTo method and you will be able to retrieve all the restaurants inside your controller. Cheers,,